# Running form simultaneously with method

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am studying C# from one book, and usually i like to polish and personalize every program just a bit more than it is done in the book.

In this one program, about Queues and Stacks, the people are ordering and eating a lot of meals. I though how good would it be to put in info TextBox something like:

```
Person x is eating y meal... (Sleep few seconds)
Person x ate y meal.
Person x is eating z meal... (Sleep...)
Person x ate z meal.
```

I did that, but the problem is when program is in loop:

`for (i< numberOfMeals)
print text on form and sleep`

The whole form is disabled and you can't do anything else while program is in that loop. On the internet i found something about barrier, is that appropriate solution. This is my first C# book, so i don't know if this problem is something i should just get over?

Comment: While your exact question hasn't been asked before, there are lots of similar ones: search e.g. for _"form freezes"_ or _"keep GUI responsive"_. Two very brief hints: Look into performing work in the background using [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ywkkz4s1.aspx) (somewhat old-fashioned these days, but easy to understand and use), or into the [Task Parallel Library (TPL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) (more modern, but with a steeper learning curve).

Comment: Yes, i found what i was looking for (getting bugs, still working on it). Anyway, thank you, I would never come up to search for "GUI freeze".

Comment: That's how duplicate questions can actually be useful: They phrase an already known problem in a different way, and thus add a new path to existing solutions. – Glad to hear you've found something of use!